# What is the set of cards used in the Wisconsin/Berg Card Sorting task?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, clinical-psychology

I'm a little confused about what cards are included in the Wisconsin card sorting task. According to PEBL there are two sets of cards available for the task, one set of 64 cards and one set of 128 cards. I think I've figured out what the 64 card deck is given that there are four different number, four different colours and four different shapes. Consequently, 4*4*4=64. However, what is contained in the 128 card deck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 64 card version is just a shorter version, according to [(Greve, 2001)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1076/clin.15.2.228.1901). Instead of running 128 total trials, there are only 64. The original test was developed and, crucially, normed for 128 trials. However, this version takes a long time to administer, and clinicians were interested in a shorter version. It was found that cutting the number of trials in half worked reasonably well.

So the short answer seems to be that the decks are the same.

Comment: This can be confirmed further [Evaluation of a Short-Form of the Berg Card Sorting Test (Fox, 2013)](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0063885).